# Local host not connecting after windows 10 update

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp

My local host and my web files were working very fine before I updated my windows 10. Immediately after the update, I tried loading my files on Firefox and it showed "localhost refused to connect", on Microsoft edge it shows "the connection was reset". I've tried loading my files on two other browsers apart from the ones mentioned and error messages still show up.

I uninstalled xampp and installed it again,loaded my files to it again but it's still not working.

Please can anyone help me with a fix to this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Check the Log in Xampp, you might get a detailed error there..

Comment: Check if any ports used by Xampp is being used by other apps and hence blocked. Especially Apache, Tomcat, MySQL/MariaDB ports...

Comment: No port is blocked. Apache and MySQL runs very well. I discovered that using sessions in my codes makes the connection blocked. So if I remove the sessions, it loads. I feel there has to be something with the Windows 10 update that's affecting the browsers connection with local host. I just can't figure out what it is